# Insertar varias fechas (estructuras en C)

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

Estoy realizando un función en el que tengo que hacer que se guarde varias fechas dentro de estructuras, la ejecución en la función principal debe salir así:

```
Introduzca fechas, 0 0 0 para acabar:
Introduzca dia, mes y anio: 20 12 19
Introduzca dia, mes y anio: 17 05 16
Introduzca dia, mes y anio: 06 01 98
Introduzca dia, mes y anio: 30 03 02
Introduzca dia, mes y anio:  0  0  0

Process returned 0 (0x0)
Press ENTER to continue.
```

(Los días deben estar entre 1 y 30, los meses entre 1 y 12, y los años entre 0 y 99 para que se guarden los datos)

He comprobado el código, me da error al compilar y no encuentro el error que tengo. ¿Podrían decirme qué error hay? ¿o si se podría hacer la función insertar más fácil o simplificada? (Insertar tiene que devolver 1 si se han leído los datos y 0 si la lista está llena). Este es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 30

struct Fecha {
    int dia, mes, anio;
};

struct Lista {
    int tam; //Cantidad de valores del array siguiente
    struct Fecha vectorFechas[N];     // Array de fechas
};

int insertar (struct Lista *, struct Fecha);

int main()
{
    struct Lista lfechas;
    struct Fecha fecha1;
    insertar(&lfechas, fecha1);
    return 0;
}

int insertar (struct Lista *listafechas, struct Fecha fecha1)
{
    int i;
    printf("Introduzca fechas, 0 0 0 para acabar:\n");

    (*listafechas).vectorFechas[0].dia = 1;
    (*listafechas).vectorFechas[0].mes = 1;
    (*listafechas).vectorFechas[0].dia = 1;

    for(i = 1; i <= N && (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].dia && (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].mes && (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].anio; i++)
    {
        do{
            printf("Introduzca dia mes y anio: ");
            scanf("%d %d %d", &(*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].dia, &(*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].mes, &(*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].anio);
        }while( ( (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].dia > 30 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].dia < 1 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].mes > 12 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].mes < 1 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].anio > 99 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].anio < 0 ) && ( vectorFechas[i-1].dia || vectorFechas[i-1].mes || vectorFechas[i-1].anio ) );
    }

    if(i == N) return 0;
    else return 1;

}
```

El compilador da error en esta línea (dentro de la función insertar):

```
    }while( ( (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].dia > 30 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].dia < 1 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].mes > 12 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].mes < 1 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].anio > 99 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].anio < 0 ) && ( vectorFechas[i-1].dia || vectorFechas[i-1].mes || vectorFechas[i-1].anio ) );
```

Comment: "*El compilador da error en esta línea*". ¿Qué error?

Answer (score 1):

Estás tratando de acceder al miembro `vectorFechas` sin hacer referencia a la estructura que lo contiene, en tu caso: `listaFechas`, lo cuál el compilador interpreta como una variable `vectorFechas` que no existe en el scope de la función `instertar()`.

Problema desde el punto de vista de tu compilador:

```
                                                ¿Qué es esto?
                                                      v         
(*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].anio < 0 ) && ( vectorFechas[i-1].di
```

Cambia:

```
 }while( ( (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].dia > 30 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].dia < 1 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].mes > 12 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].mes < 1 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].anio > 99 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].anio < 0 ) && ( vectorFechas[i-1].dia || vectorFechas[i-1].mes || vectorFechas[i-1].anio ) );
```

Por:

```
}while( ( (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].dia > 30 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].dia < 1 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].mes > 12 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].mes < 1 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].anio > 99 || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].anio < 0 ) && ( (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].dia || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].mes || (*listafechas).vectorFechas[i-1].anio ) );
```